# Cannot get insertId after a mysql insert

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, axios

Set up: react, axios, mysql, node.js

I am trying to access the results.insertId from mysql in an axios post request after an insert and I see that it logs the correct result, but after that when I try to to assign it to a state, it return empty. I have seen that it could be an async issue but I do not understand the issue here since I can log the data properly. I also am new to promises and async but the end goal is to insert a page element in mysql and then using the id of the new page as a variable to redirect the user to the created page if anyone has a better solution, I am open to anything.

My node.js statement:

```js
app.post('/api/insertpage', (req, res) => {

    const name = req.body.name;
    const Link = req.body.Link;

    const sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO pages (name, Link) VALUES (?,?);";   
    
    db.query(sqlInsert, [name, Link], (err, results) => {

        if (err) {
            res.send({ err: err });        
            console.log("the error is:" + err);
        }

        if (results.insertId) {
            res.json({ insertId: results.insertId })
            console.log(results);
            console.log(results.insertId);
        } else {
            res.send({ message: "not working"});
            res.send("not working"); 
        }
    })
});
```

my axios request:

```js
Axios.post("backendurl/api/insertpage" , {
      name: name,
      Link: Link,
  })
  .then((results) => {     
      console.log(results.data.insertId);
      setPageId(results.data.insertId); 
// my state is defined in a functional component as  const [pageId, setPageId] = useState();
// I also tried with useState("");
      console.log(results.data)
      if (results.data.message) {
          console.log("failed")

      } else {
          if (results.data.insertId) {
              console.log("id present")
                  console.log(results.data.insertId);
                  console.log(pageId);
                  
          }  else {
                  console.log("no id")
              }
          if (pageId !== "") {
              console.log("id NOT null IT IS WORKING")
              console.log(pageId);
          } else {
              console.log("id IS null")
          }
      }
   })
```

Here is what a log looks like, logging the insertId first, and then the full response:

[image]

Comment: Based on your client-side code, it seems you want `res.json({ insertId: results.insertId })` in your backend code instead of `res.send(results.insertId)`

Comment: Unfortunately I just tried and it doesn't work. I still log the id correctly but the state is returning as undefined or null if I set it as a string. It won't pass the value that just logged.

Comment: You'd also need to use `setPageId(results.data.insertId)` in your frontend. Just be consistent with your data structures

Comment: Yeah I did that too, still return nothing in the state.

Comment: done sorry about that